# What's wrong with this php foreach code?

Tags: php

```
<?php

$sessionTotal = 10;

        for($initial = 1; $initial <= $sessionTotal ; $initial++){
            echo '<input type="text" name="menuItems" size="20" /><br /><br/>';
        }

    //I have a if statement here checking if the submit button isset, yada yada, after I press the submit button, it returns this error -> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\yada\yada-yada.php on line 43

    foreach($_POST['menuItems'] as $value)
    {
    echo $value;
    }

?>
```

It will echo $value after it is submitted. I have a if statement checking if the submit button isset, yada yada, after I press the submit button, it returns this error -> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\yada\yada-yada.php on line 43

Comment: your post dont habe a menuItems entry! post the output of `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: or $_POST['menuItems'] is not an array..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST['menuItems']` is not an array, `foreach` only accepts arrays and certain objects.

If you make it

```
<?php

$sessionTotal = 10;

        for($initial = 1; $initial <= $sessionTotal ; $initial++){
            echo '<input type="text" name="menuItems[]" size="20" /><br /><br/>';
        }

    //I have a if statement here checking if the submit button isset, yada yada, after I press the submit button, it returns this error -> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\yada\yada-yada.php on line 43

    if ( is_array( $_POST['menuItems'] ) ) 
    foreach($_POST['menuItems'] as $value)
    {
    echo $value;
    }

?>
```

It should work.

Comment: Cool, thanks, man. It works now, why does [] make it an array?
*I'll accept your answer in 8 minutes, it wouldn't allow me to accept before 8 minutes*

Comment: -1 for not explaining why exactly those `[]` are needed. With your answer the OP may have a working example, but still hasn't got the first clue about why this happened in the first place.

Comment: @MouseHello because that's how array's are designated: variable[key], if you don't put a a key ,it creates a new value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your `foreach`. There is something wrong with your understanding of how PHP parses input-attributes (_POST, _GET).

---

```
<input type="text" name="foobar" value="one">
<input type="text" name="foobar" value="two">
<input type="text" name="foobar" value="three">
```

translates to the [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#form-content-type) representation `foobar=one&foobar=two&foobar=three`.

PHP parses this string into a map (associative array). It does this somewhat like the following code:

```
<?php
$_GET = array();
$string = 'foobar=one&foobar=two&foobar=three';
$parts = explode('&', $string);
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $p = explode('=', $part);
    $_GET[urldecode($p[0])] = urldecode($p[1]);
}
```

So basically it is assigning `$_GET['foobar']` three times, leaving `$_GET['foobar'] === 'three'`.

Translated, this is what is happening here:

```
$_GET['foobar'] = 'one';
$_GET['foobar'] = 'two';
$_GET['foobar'] = 'three';
```

At this point I'd like to note that other languages (Ruby, Java, …) deal with this quite differently. Ruby for example recognizes the repeating key and builds something similar to `$_GET['foobar'] = array('one', 'two', 'three')`.

---

There is a simple "trick" to tell PHP that the repeating value should be parsed into an array:

```
<input type="text" name="foobar[]" value="one">
<input type="text" name="foobar[]" value="two">
<input type="text" name="foobar[]" value="three">
```

will lead to `$_GET['foobar'] = array('one', 'two', 'three')`;

Translated, this is what is happening here:

```
$_GET['foobar'][] = 'one';
$_GET['foobar'][] = 'two';
$_GET['foobar'][] = 'three';
```

(Note: `$array[] = 'value'` is the same as `array_push($array, 'value')`)

So whenever you're dealing with repeating key names (or `<select multiple>`) you want to add `[]` to the name, so PHP builds an array from it.

You may also want to know that you can actually specify the array-keys:

```
<input type="text" name="foobar[hello][world]" value="one">
```

will lead to `$_GET['foobar']['hello']['world'] == 'one'`.